# How to associate Imagelist property with ImageIndex property in Objectinspector at design time?

Tags: c#, delphi

surely you know the easy manipulation in object inspector at design time with ImageList and ImageIndex properties. After assigning Imagelist you can click on ImageIndex property, and nice list of images togeather with their indexes appears. 
I am trying to make my own control, which has imagelist and imageindex properties. But I wonder, how can I let object inspector "know" (or make it aware), that my defined imageindex property should be picked up from combobox. (which is built in object inspector itself)
Does anybody know the trick?

thanx very much

Comment: Your use of the term "object inspector" suggests you're using Delphi. You tagged this question as C#, too; why? Developing components for those two languages is not the same.

Comment: yes, I tried to make this component in C# at the start I have more skills to use Delphi though and I also met this problem in the past in the Delphi too. 
I posted a lot of questions regarding Delphi problems here in stackoverflow and within few hours (minutes) I got answer. So I tried to mark it as C# too. There are 20 times more C# tags, so I 

expected swift answer. ;-). According to (no c#) reaction so far, I learn, what the sentece "Delphi has strong community" means.... :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have never tried to do this, but I would suspect that this will work:

In your component, declare the `ImageIndex` property not as `integer`, but as `TImageIndex`.

That is, write (for instance)

```
private
  FImageIndex: TImageIndex;
published
  property ImageIndex: TImageIndex read FImageIndex write SetImageIndex default -1;
```

instead of

```
private
  FImageIndex: integer;
published
  property ImageIndex: integer read FImageIndex write SetImageIndex default -1;
```

`TImageIndex` is defined as

```
type
  TImageIndex = type Integer;
```

so it is really an integer, but a different type.

(As a footnote, if the definition had been

```
type
  TImageIndex = Integer;
```

then `TImageIndex` would have been just another name of `Integer`, and so noone (not even the IDE) would have been able to distinguish `TImageIndex` from `Integer`. Now they are two different types, but, of course, assignment-compatible ones.)

Comment: No, that does not work... The problem is (what I see), that you must somewhere declare, that this ImageIndex belongs to that Imagelist. Imagine you have 3 ImageLists and 3 imageindexes. How object inspector "knows" which belongs to what?

Comment: @Iyborko: It might be that *too*, yes.

Comment: I tried it now... In fact one thing is changed: instead of the edit box, by which you can edit integer values, combobox arrow appeared  when I tried edit imageindex value. I appreciate your answers very much and I say sorry, if my No might sounded a little bit arrogant...

Comment: @Lyborko, you're off to a good start. The first step is indeed to use `TImageIndex` as the property type. The next step is to figure out how to associate a `TImageList` with the component you're editing, which itself probably doesn't have an `ImageList` or `Images` property. Its *owner* or *container* might, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit more complicated than Andreas suggested. You can study the way the Jedi VCL handles this. Search for *TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty* in the Design folder as a start.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the Object Inspector to be aware of, you have to register a Property Editor in your design package.

If you're using jvcl take a look at the TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty class defined in the jvcl\design\JvDsgnEditors.

After you have it, to in your register procedure call RegisterPropertyEditor like this:

```
begin
  RegisterPropertyEditor(TypeInfo(TImageIndex), TMyComponent, 'ImageIndex',TJvDefaultImageIndexProperty);
end;
```

For clarification, take a look at the jvcl\design\JvStdCtrlsReg.pas or google for Delphi OTA examples.